# AWS cloudwatch Event : how distinguish multi domain in a source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-media-convert, usermetadata

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.mediaconvert"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "MediaConvert Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "COMPLETE",
      "ERROR"
    ]
  }
}
```

My Follow:

- Domain A: upload video to aws3 bukket A -> lambda create job mediaconvert ->
  cloudwatch Event rule (check complete) -> Call lambda call API of
  domain A
- Domain B: upload video to aws3 bukket B -> lambda create job
  mediaconvert -> cloudwatch Event rule (check complete) -> Call lambda
  call API of domain B

> At cloudwatch Event rule: How can i distinguish domain A and domain B ?

I tried to use "userMetadata" but incorrect

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Event Patterns have [a more strict format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html) comparing to a simple JSON. It gets a key and verifies if the according event value is inside *the list* of values. So you can't set a value as a string inside a pattern. Use a list of values instead.

Example:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.mediaconvert"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "MediaConvert Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "COMPLETE",
      "ERROR"
    ],
  "userMetadata": {
    "domain": [
        "A"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That is exactly the same what the error says. You can use only arrays as leaves of an event pattern.